# Filter meta_query Wordpress result through another wp filter

Tags: wordpress

Firstly, SORRY for the title, I have no idea how to explain this in a few words!

I have a query that removes posts/pages from the main_query where they have a meta key.

However, on a particular page (the front page) I want to filter by a single category too (front page news). I tried adding the code below but it breaks.

Can anyone help me refine this please?

For clarity, I want to filter by the meta_keys globally and the meta_keys AND the category for one template only, front-page.php

`function hide_private_posts( $query ) {

```
// If user isn't logged in, hide all private posts / pages
if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {

    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(

            array(
                  'key' => 'smartPrivate',
                  'value' => 'smartPrivate_loggedIn',
                  'compare' => '!='
            ),
            array(
                  'key' => 'smartPrivate',
                  'value' => 'smartPrivate_loggedInMentors',
                  'compare' => '!='
            )

        ));
    }

    // If user is logged in but a learner, show logged in posts / pages
    } else if( is_user_sso_role( array('learner') ) ) {

    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(

            array(
                  'key' => 'smartPrivate',
                  'value' => 'smartPrivate_loggedInMentors',
                  'compare' => '!='
            )

        ));
        }

    } // Else don't filter posts and pages

    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        query_posts( $query . '&category_name=front-page-news' );
    }

return $query;
}
add_filter('pre-get-posts' , 'hide_private_posts');`
```

Answer (score 0):

OK - in the interests of closing this off.

The query I was using `query_posts` seems to reset the loop and override the meta_queries placed in previously.

So, this works fine and retains the meta_query filtering.

```
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'category_name', 'front-page-news');
}
```